# Override render :json in no model object Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I need override "render json" but I don't need override this for models, in models I know that I can open up ActiveRecord::Base and overriding as_json method. But my problem is when I have something like this

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

def index
   render json: { field: 'is a test' }
end

end
```

My problem is because I use a gem in which some methods I need to return "render json" and this gem not has centralized a method for this. I think in do fork of the gem and refactor this for I can overriding centralized method, but first I want to know if is possible overriding the render.

Comment: is there an actual problem here? that code is fine.

Comment: Please specify the gem. Is that Active Model Serializers?

Comment: The problem is that I want that "render json" not return {field: 'is a test'} I want to  my custom json format example { status: 'ok', response: {field: 'is a test'} } .

Comment: My problem is with the gem Opro and response /oauth/token or whatever

Comment: Can't you use `{ status: 'ok', response: {field: 'is a test'} }` directly?

Comment: No because the gem Opro using render json in your controller. Then I would know if possible override render, if not, i fork the gem and override the methods. The attach code is only a example for that you understand that i don't overriding a render json in a model, but is a simple example, my really problem is with the response in the gem

Comment: The question looks specific to this gem. It seems you can override the engine and add customization without fork and hack, though I don't have experience on the gem.

Comment: Is other way, but without fork I will need override all method with render json and this not seems good, but thnk for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open ActionController::Base class and override render method there. However I am not sure whether this is the best idea, it depends on actual trouble you are having and you didn't give us too much details about the problem, i.e. what would you expect to get and what you are actually getting.

UPDATE

I would probably go with sth like:

```
class ActionController::Base
  def render *args
    options = args.extract_options!
    if options[:json]
      \\ do whatever you need here
    end
    args << options
    super *args
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I tell you. I've a api my normal api response is:

{ status:'ok', response: {field:'is a example'} }

I want to implement oauth for my api, then I saw the gem Opro(https://github.com/opro/opro) but in this gem the controllers response:

{field:'is a example'}

I've a ApiController which inheritance "ActionController::Base" and it has two method for preparing response correctly. Then in my api's controller when render json call my methods and working fine with my format, but the opro's controller simply render json like rails default.

Comment: Then my question is, I can override the rails render json response for the opro's controller render json with my format?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you can't. This is ruby - we can do everything we need. If the problem is for your API controller only you can override it there, but I understand you want to improve the gem itself. If so, you'll need to override render in a module gem uses for enhancing the controller (obviously). However since original render method is rather complicated I would probably tried to reuse as much of original version as possible. Maybe sth like code I added to answer?

Comment: Thnk!! I work for me! I applied your code in the override gem controller and it's work! Thank you!!